# JMeter executing samplers in sequential order wherein each subsequent request depends on the response of the preceding one?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, api-testing, performance-testing, testing-framework

I have a JMeter script wherein the thread group has eight samplers and each sampler depends on the response of the preceding one. When I run this jmx script with 'Number of Threads' as one, it works fine but when I increase the number things fall apart and many requests fail as the sequence of execution breaks!

To handle this, as a Post Processor to my first sampler I added a Beanshell Post-Processor with ${__setProperty(ThreadValue,${__threadNum},)} in the script area. Then I kept the rest of the samplers in individual If Controllers with Condition as (${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}==true) && (${__property(ThreadValue,,)} == ${__threadNum})

But now only the top two samplers get executed multiple times and the rest get executed only once! What maybe the reason?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing something very weird. JMeter threads are **totally independent** and each thread has its own context, variables, cookies, etc.

So

- If you have 1 thread - it will execute 8 requests in sequential order (upside down)
- If you have 2 threads - each of 2 threads will execute 8 requests in sequential order
- etc.

So I would recommend removing your Beanshell Post-Processor and If Controller as they are not required at all. If you need to perform some synchronization between different threads you should go for [Inter-Thread Communication](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) plugin (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager))

---

With regards to your question itself, as per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; **properties are common to all threads**

So when you define the property it is defined **globally** and will be available to **all** threads until JMeter is restarted

Comment: So how do I execute 8 requests in a single thread group with a large 'Number of Threads (users)' like 100. Requests are processed fine with Number of threads as 1 but when the number is increased most of them fail!